# Direct link to category?

Tags: categories

I'm trying to build up a menu of category links for specific categories I'd like to highlight and apply styling/classes to.

I've tried this sort of thing.

```
<li><a href="<?php get_site_url(); ?>category/Gadgets"> Gadgets</a></li>
```

And

```
 <li><a href="category/Gadgets"> Gadgets</a></li>
```

It's showing up as sitename/category/category/category/gadgets on the front end.

I can't use `<?php wp_list_categories('orderby=name&title_li='); ?>` because it's going to spit out all of them and limit the styling I can do on the html.

I just want to link to categories directly, by name, preferably without hard coding in the site name.

Answer (score 2):

There is a function called get_category_link() which might be helpful for you. This will be able to generate an appropriate link without having to hard-code it, except for the category name or ID.

Examples from the Wordpress Codex:

```
<?php
    // Get the ID of a given category
    $category_id = get_cat_ID( 'Category Name' );

    // Get the URL of this category
    $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );
?>

<!-- Print a link to this category -->
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" title="Category Name">Category Name</a>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link

Answer (score 1):

Specific to your demand, try this:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo home_url() ?>/category/Gadgets"> Gadgets</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `wp_list_categories('include=3,5,9,16');`, replace "3,5,9,16" with your category ids ( comma separated

another method

```
get_category_link( $category_id );
```

see wordpress codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link)

One more method is to create category menu in admin and print it in your theme ( if theme supports menus )

Answer (score 0):

`get_site_url()` [returns a string with the URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_url), it does not print it. So you may try

```
<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>
```

or better:

```
<?= get_site_url(); ?>
```